# Whats wrong with this C program?

Tags: c

It should give me the number of inputs entered by the user. But it gives 100. I compiled with gcc.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int arr[100];
int count=0;
int max=100;


int main(){
 int i, input;
 printf("Enter integer values one by one, q to quit.\n");
 for(i=0;i<max;i++){
  scanf("%d",&input);
  arr[i]=input;
  if(input=='q')break;
  count++;
 }
 printf("You entered %d values.\n",count);
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try using an integer value, like -1, instead of 'q'.

Comment: You can exit by entering 113.

Comment: @Paul-R Its not my college homework. Its a self practice. I was developing a larger program which apparently stuck me for hours. Later I found the trap, cut shorted to make it into a simpler situation and posted :) 
And yeah, I want it the q way, not a no. like -1. I did with strings. Works fine now.

@Kenny Putting 113 doesn't work.

Comment: Obligatory: don't use `scanf`. http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html

Comment: Very useful info. Thanks a lot James

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are reading into a numeric variable, it can't really have the value 'q', so your test won't work. If you want to write code like this, you should read user input into a string, check to see if the string contains "q" and if not convert it to an integer.

Comment: Maybe you're supposed to type 113 to exit

Comment: @ Matti  It did occur to me to suggest that, but I thought it would be too cruel...

Comment: That's a bit incorrect... a numerical variable can have a value of 'q' - i.e. ascii code of q. char is technically an integer number. It will work if user enters ascii value of 'q' as a decimal number.

Comment: @SigTerm: I think Neil was just trying to avoid confusing the poor fellow

Comment: @SigTerm I agree with you. I coded using the same logic but it didn't work out. Although it worked with the string way, as Neil wrote, but I want it the char/int way.

Answer (score 3):

`scanf` has a return value. Use it to test if scanf was actually able to parse anything. In your scenario, 'q' will never be stored in the variable `input`, being it as a char or numerical representation. You cannot read "q" as "%d" and therefore scanf will silently fail.

Test for the return value of scanf to decide for a `break`.

Comment: scanf is returning me 0 if I enter q and 1 if I enter any integer.

Comment: Exactly. Scanf returns the numbers of variables that could successfully be parsed/stored. So if it is less than you want, you can expect failure and in your case, do the 'break'; Read the manpage of scanf for a thorough explanation.

Answer (score 1):

scanf %d does not understand 'q'. You can check the return value of scanf though - if it returns 0 the user did not enter a valid number.

If only q and not other non-numeric strings should terminate the loop, read into a string and check if it's q and if not convert it to an int with atoi().

Answer (score 0):

Cute. Entering `'q'` causes the scanf to fail, with `input` left at whatever the last value was. This broken loop continues to the end of the range. The test `input=='q'` never succeeds, of course.

Answer (score 0):

:)
Let me modify this program like this:

```
#include <stdio.h> 

int arr[100]; 
int count=0; 
int max=100; 


int main(){ 
 int i, input; 
 printf("Enter integer values one by one, -1 to quit.\n"); 
 for(i=0;i<max;i++){ 
  scanf("%d",&input); 
  arr[i]=input; 
  if(input==-1)break; 
  count++; 
 } 
 printf("You entered %d values.\n",count); 
 return 0; 
}
```

You can't use a numeric var to get a char value.
If you change it just like this, it will work. 
:)

Answer (score 0):

scanf will return 0 in your code when the input character does not match the conversion specification. But, the **next call** to scanf will resume searching immediately after the last converted character. Therefore, you can try the below code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int arr[100];
int count=0;
int max=100;


int main(){
   int i, input, ret;
   char end; 
   printf("Enter integer values one by one, q to quit.\n");
   for(i=0;i<max;i++)
   {
      ret = scanf("%d",&input);
      if (!ret)
      {
         scanf("%c", &end);
         if ( end == 'q')
            break;
         else
           continue;
      }
      arr[i]=input;
      count++;
   }
   printf("You entered %d values.\n",count);
   return 0;
}
```

By doing this, you can make sure that control does not come out of the loop unless you enter q and only legitimate values are copied to the array.

Answer (score -1):

you exit the program by typing the ascii value for 'q' not q/